# Remove Google Map Marker Text

Tags: google-maps, embed

I have a client who has embedded Google Maps showing the location of a new hospital they are building. Until recently it just showed the pin marker, however now it is showing the longitude and latitude next to the pin. I have tried everything to remove this text but none of the options in the query string appear to do anything.

[image: This is an example of the text I need to remove]

I think Google has updated the embed code but I can't find any documentation about it though. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1):

From the research I did, it seems like the new Google maps is pretty rigid and there isn't really a simple way. I think it would require some more complex API stuff.

This is the post that I found that described the limitations [Removing the info window from an embedded map in the new Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258230/removing-the-info-window-from-an-embedded-map-in-the-new-google-maps)

Sorry I realize that doesn't really help.

Comment: I ended up using a pre-built WordPress plugin to achieve the desired effect. I went that route due to limited time requirements. Thanks for confirming my suspicions though.